# Как получить полный url

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, bs4

У меня такой вопрос.
Вот я с помощью цикла перебрал ссылки из массива.

```
def get_page_link(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
print(str.strip(title))


counter = 0
for link_container in link_containers:
    a_tag = link_container .find("a")
    # Если нашел
    if a_tag:
        link = a_tag.get("href")
        print(link)
    else:
        counter += 1
print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")
```

И при выводе он мне ссылки по типу "/4980254-tokaev-prinyal-novogo-akima-almaty-i.html" 
Нужно чтобы была полная ссылка по типу "https://www.zakon.kz/4980254-tokaev-prinyal-novogo-akima-almaty-i.html"

Вот сам полный код (если надо будет)

```
#Парсер v1 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))


    counter = 0
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            print(link)
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    get_page_link(get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде HTML страницы используются "относительные ссылки".
Можете печатать полную ссылку, либо:

```
print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
```

Либо:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

print(urljoin(url, link))
```

В этом случае, необходимо передать в `get_page_link` текущий `url`.

---

Полный код1:

```
#Парсер v1 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))


    counter = 0
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            print(f'https://www.zakon.kz{link}')
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    get_page_link(get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Полный код2:

```
#Парсер v1 by Raha
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok: # 200  ## 403 404
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def get_page_link(url, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title =soup.find('h1',{'class':'roboto'}).text
    link_containers=soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
    print(str.strip(title))


    counter = 0
    for link_container in link_containers:
        a_tag = link_container .find("a")
        # Если нашел
        if a_tag:
            link = a_tag.get("href")
            print(urljoin(url, link))
        else:
            counter += 1
    print(f"Ошибок нашлось {counter}")


def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/'
    get_page_link(url, get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```